# How to get rid of default date "1899-12-30" in my time data

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I import my Excel file to SQL Server, it automatically add a default date to my time data. For example, my original data looks like this:

```
StartTime         EndTime
----------------------------
09:00 AM          10:00 AM
```

But when I load the data in SQL Server, it adds the default date like this

```
StartTime                   EndTime
----------------------------------------------------
1899-12-30 09:00:00.000     1899-12-30 10:00:00.000
```

How do I get rid of this default date and also those trailing zeros?

Comment: How exactly are you importing it? You don't want to remove the trailing zeros' because you want to store it as a time (not a string).

Answer (score 3):

You can convert to time:

```
select convert(time, starttime), convert(time, endtime)
```

You can also be sure that the type in the table is `time`.

Answer (score 0):

You might be having the datatype as `DATETIME`. Now, you can convert the datatype to `TIME` to remove the datevalues. In future, remember to keep the datatype as TIME to avoid these issues.

```sql
CREATE TABLE #T (timeval DATETIME)

insert into #T 
VALUES ('09:00 AM'),('10:00 AM')

ALTER TABLE #T 
ALTER COLUMN timeval TIME  

SELECT * FROM #T
```

```
+------------------+
|     timeval      |
+------------------+
| 09:00:00.0000000 |
| 10:00:00.0000000 |
+------------------+
```